# Connection error with mongodb using Rmongo

Tags: r, mongodb, angular, meteor, rmongo

I am running meteor application in a localhost on port 3000 and I can't connect R with my MongoDB. ( I checked this code for MongoDB running on port 27017 without meteor - just pure database and it's working properly). Meteor create an own database which is calling meteor and inside are my collections ( including images in this sample).

```
 library(RMongo)
 mongo<- mongoDbConnect("meteor", host="127.0.0.1", port=3000) #error
 #mongo<- mongoDbConnect("meteor", host="127.0.0.1", port=27017)# - that's work 

 output <- dbGetQuery(mongo, 'images', '{}')
 print(output)
```

I have this error:

> error in '.jcall(rmongo.object@javaMongo, "S", "dbGetQuery", collection, ':
>
> com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server /127.0.0.1:3000 failed on database meteor
>
> dbGetQuery ... dbGetQueryForKeys -> dbGetQueryForKeys -> .jcall -> .jcheck -> .Call

EDIT:
the same problem with any other R packages like mongolite

> No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection closed calling ismaster on 'localhost:3000']

Answer (score 1):

In case that somebody else will have this problem:
type:

```
 meteor mongo -U
```

to get URL address of your db, and now copy paste to host:""